# What do i do so that the output will be: Hello "name". How old are you?

Tags: java

How do I send a String variable from method 'name' to  method 'main', and from there send it to method age?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);   
        String name = "";
        name(scanner, name);
        age(scanner, name);
    }
    static String name(Scanner scanner, String name) {
        System.out.println("Pls, enter your name: ");
        name = scanner.nextLine();
        while(name.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Pls, enter your name: ");
            name = scanner.nextLine();
        }
        return name;
        }       
    
    static void age(Scanner scanner, String name){
        System.out.println("Hello, " + name + ". How old are you?");
    } 
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `name` parameter to the `name` method. Just define a local variable. Then, use the return value: `String name = name(scanner);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass name as parameter, but you rather want to return it from the method call.
Below works, but you also probably want to rename 'name' method to something else, like 'getName' to avoid confusion.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name = name(scanner);
    int age = age(scanner, name);
   //do something with Age and name here
}

static String name(Scanner scanner) {
    System.out.println("Pls, enter your name: ");
    String name = scanner.nextLine();
    while(name.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Pls, enter your name: ");
        name = scanner.nextLine();
    }
    return name;
}

static int age(Scanner scanner, String name){
    System.out.println("Hello, " + name + ". How old are you?");
    //int age = ...
    return age;
}
```